# Getting Serverless Deployment bucket error when using serverless-deployment-bucket plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

So in my serverless.yaml file, I am using serverless-deployment-bucket plugin .

I am trying to achieve is, to create a new bucket using this plugin and deploy my lambda function code in this custom defined bucket (created using serverless-deployment-bucket plugin ) instead of the default s3 bucket that sls framework uses.

But I am getting this following error when I am trying to deploy my lambda code :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoDqe.png)

Following is the snippet of my serverless.yaml file :

provider:
name: aws
runtime: python3.8
role: TestIAMRole
stage: dev
region: us-east-1
stackName: sample1
deploymentBucket:
name: samplebucket456754
serverSideEncryption: AES256
blockPublicAccess: true

functions:
hello:
handler: handler.hello

plugins:

serverless-deployment-bucket
serverless-puresec-cli